# Issue with select element styling

Tags: html, css

Form with   user text input and submit button form styling works perfectly fine.

Now i need to add a drop down box to the same form. After adding the drop down menu, styling is not perfect.

Please help me to resolve the same.

My HTML Code :

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" id="cf-form">

    <select name="amt">
        <option value="10">Mobile Phones</option>
        <option value="20">Tablets</option>
        <option value="50">Camera</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="valbox" placeholder="Search here..." required>
    <button type="submit" id="butval">Search</button>
</form>
```

MY CSS File :

```
.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 15%;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   
/* Form text input */

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}
.cf:before, .cf:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}

.cf{
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: "*.. styling is not perfect..*: What styling are you after?

Comment: @abhitalks I mean not properly aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some CSS3 tutorials.

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ky353L3/) - i aligned your elements...

Just added:

```
.form-wrapper select {
    float: left;   
    width: 15%;
}
```

and changed these two in `.form-wrapper input`

```
width: 66%;
padding: 40px 2%;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Der Vampyr sure i will go though the tutorials